# MaaS not recognizing HP logical drives

Tags: hp, juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I have a MaaS server setup and working with HP blades. In order to do a JuJu openstack install all the servers need two disks, which I accomplished by creating two logical drives on each blade.

The issue is that MaaS does not see this and only creates a ~1.4GB partition. Anyone have any ideas why?